# Windows - Get HWND from TreeView for GetScrollInfo?

Tags: .net, winapi, treeview, hwnd

I'm new to Windows programming and trying to get the position of a TreeView's scroll bar.

```
SCROLLINFO scrollInfo;
ZeroMemory(&scrollInfo, sizeof(scrollInfo));
scrollInfo.cbSize = sizeof(scrollInfo);
scrollInfo.fMask = SIF_TRACKPOS;
tbool gotScrollInfo = GetScrollInfo(poTreeView->Handle, SB_VERT, &scrollInfo);
```

I get an error:

> `'BOOL GetScrollInfo(HWND,int,LPSCROLLINFO)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'System::IntPtr' to 'HWND'.`

I've looked online and cannot find how to get from the TreeView pointer to an `HWND`.  Windows' documentation assumes you already have the HWND.

I've seen other places where people use `TreeView.hwnd` or cast `TreeView.Handle` to an `IntPtr` - I guess the function used to take that instead of an `HWND`?

Does anyone know how to do this? this should be super simple, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: What language is that?  Post your pinvoke call that you are using for GetScrollInfo.  Generally, yes, treeView1.Handle is the HWND you are looking for.

Comment: The `.net` tag is useless. What language are you writing your code in? Managed or unmanaged? Where's your declaration for `GetScrollInfo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`Control.Handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.handle?view=netframework-4.7.2) documentation:

> An IntPtr that contains the window handle (HWND) of the control.
>
> ...
>
> **The value of the Handle property is a Windows HWND.** If the handle has not yet been created, referencing this property will force the handle to be created.

So yes, you can simply type-cast the `IntPtr` to an `HWND`, eg:

```
(HWND)(poTreeView->Handle.ToPointer())
```

Or

```
static_cast<HWND>(poTreeView->Handle.ToPointer())
```